# What does "new ClassName(this);" mean?

Tags: c++, qt, documentation

For example:

```
// name.h
Class A {
   private:
          QLabel *statusLabel;
};

// name.cpp
statusLabel = new QLabel(this);
```

Is this **constructor-calling**? I don't think so, but if it's - for what? ***statusLabel*** is already **QLabel-Class** object.

Comment: `statusLabel` is a **pointer** to `QLabel`. It is not already a `QLabel` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this constructor-calling?

It's a *new-expression*, used to create a dynamic object. It

- allocates some memory;
- creates a `QLabel` object in that memory, by calling a constructor with `this` (a pointer to the current object) as the argument;
- returns a pointer to the new object, which you assign to `statusLabel`.

> `statusLabel` is already `QLabel`-Class object.

No, the `*` indicates that it's a pointer, not an object. Until you assign it to point to an object (as this line of code does), it doesn't represent any object. Once assigned, you can use it to access the object it points to.

Answer (score 1):

In the header you indicate that Class A has a pointer towards a QLabel. In the cpp file you actually creat the QLabel object. The "this" is a pointer towards the object of Class A that creates the QLabel, indicating that this object is the parent of QLabel. However, Class A is not a QWidget, so it should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
statusLabel = new QLabel(this);
```

EDITED TO BE MORE PRECISE:-

So, you are using new expression for allocating memory which indirectly would call constructor of QLabel with this as argument.